# Connecting to Oracle XE running on Docker

Tags: oracle11g, docker, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect to Oracle XE which is running on docker on my Mac.

```
docker run -d -p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521 wnameless/oracle-xe-11g

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
105d84763b6c        wnameless/oracle-xe-11g   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbi"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49160->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49161->1521/tcp   hopeful_pasteur
```

When I'm tying to connect to it via SQL Developer with following credentials:

```
hostname: localhost
port: 49161
sid: xe
username: system
password: oracle
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Failure - Test failed: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Docker log shows:

```
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using Windows or OSX so you should not use localhost for the hostname instead that you should use your docker machine's ip address i.e.

```
docker-machine ip default
>172.16.34.132
```

Comment: Why is this? Can you please explain? localhost should surely work on Windows and OS X??